# jQuery Hide Option elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="25" value="3" class="third-level-child"> -  -  - Sub Child task 1.1</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
```

To hide options with value I can use

```
$("#selectlistID option[value='3']").hide();
```

How can I hide all the option elements using class which are sub-childs ?

Comment: You should use e.g a class for all sub children, this would be better than targeting option's inner text

Comment: You can't use hide in a cross browser manner... it is better to remove those elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny the hidden option elements have values which are used for some internal calculation based on their parent. Does removing those options still fetch me the values ?

Comment: You will have to change the code which selects the elements for internal calculation...

Comment: The code checks for any parents subsequent child elements. If I remove those, won't fetch values associated with them. Is there any workaround you suggest for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contains selector:

```
$("#selectlistID option:contains('-  -  -')").hide();
```

Update: Using class selector-

```
$('option.third-level-child').hide();
```

Comment: Milind Anantwar: Do we need to pass select ID ? The above don't work

Comment: Does not matter if other dom elements do not have the same class.

Comment: It must be: `$('option.third-level-child').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the option by class as shown below,

```js
$("#selectlistID option[class='third-level-child']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectlistID">
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="25" value="3" class="third-level-child"> -  -  - Sub Child task 1.1</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
  </select>
```